# Replacing Multi-Value Fields With A Join Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm moving on from multi-value fields due to my conversion to SQL Server for the back end. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to replace it.

What I've done is created a many to many relationship between my "Opportunities" and "Purpose" tables utilizing a join table (one to many on each). This part was easy.

What I don't understand is how to then create a dropdown listbox (with check boxes to select the options) for the purpose.

I've found resources online pointing to the idea that I will need to use VBA, but have yet to find any actual examples. Is anyone familiar with how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I generally use a listbox with multiple select and some code, when required.

Comment: Unfortunately, multiple selections is not available as a datatype for SQL, and everything I've found has told me to use a join table.

Comment: I am not talking about tables, I am talking about forms. A table is for the developer, a form is for the user.

Comment: I'm developing both the forms and the tables. The form interacts with the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this for exactly the same reason; moving to a SQL Server back-end.  My solution keeps the checkbox functionality but doesn't have them in a drop-down.  You can put the check-boxes in a sub-form (that looks like a drop-down?) if you don't want a bunch of boxes on your main form.

For each checkbox you want to test for whether a record in the related table exists and add it if it doesn't when the box is checked, and the reverse when it's unchecked.  The check-boxes must be unbound for this to work.

Here's the add/remove code.  It goes in the "After Update" event:

```
Private Sub cb_1_AfterUpdate()

If Me.cb_1 = True Then
    If DCount("Parent_ID", "Checkbox_records", "Parent_ID = " & Me.P_ID & "and Checked_box_num = 1") = 0 Then
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO Checkbox_records (Parent_ID, Checked_box_num) VALUES (" & Me.P_ID & "," & "1)"
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    End If
End If

If Me.cb_1 = False Then
    If DCount("Parent_ID", "Checkbox_records", "Parent_ID = " & Me.P_ID & "and Checked_box_num = 1") > 0 Then
        strSQL = "DELETE FROM Checkbox_records WHERE Parent_ID = " & Me.P_ID & " and Checked_box_num = 1"
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

The problem with unbound boxes is that they don't change when you switch records.  So you have to set the boxes to reflect the data state when you change records, which you can do in the form's "On Current" event:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

If DCount("Parent_ID", "Checkbox_records", "Parent_ID = " & Me.P_ID & "and Checked_box_num = 1") > 0 Then
    Me.cb_1 = True
Else
    Me.cb_1 = False
End If

End Sub
```

The thing I don't like about this solution is that you have to duplicate the code for each box, but it runs smoothly so it's livable.